# Comment reply not display properly by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

For prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form I want to add return false;
Also have default browser behavior problem to refresh this page.

---

But if I add return false; or e.preventDefault(); reply of any comment show duplicate under only last/top/new comment AND after a refresh Its show original comment. not only that delete comment show loader continuously.

Now I think my problem either my html structure or JavaScript.

HTML of index.php:

```
<div class="content"><comment>

   <div class="post'.$id.'">
   //here main comment goes on
   </div>

     <div class="reply'.$id.'" id="replynext"><ul>
     //here reply goes on
     </ul></div>

<comment></div>
```

HTML of Reply.php:

```
<div class="reply'.$id.'" id="replynext"><ul>
//new reply goes here
</ul></div>
```

JS for reply without return false;:

```
var inputAuthor = $("#author");
var inputComment = $("#comment");
var inputReplycom = $(".replycom");
var inputImg = $("#img");
var inputUrl = $("#url");
var inputTutid = $("#tutid");
var inputparent_id = $("#parent_id");
var commentList = $(".content > comment");

function updateReplybox(){
var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value");
    //just for the fade effect
$.ajax({
type: "POST", url: "reply.php", data: "action=update&tutid="+ tutid,
complete: function(data){
var RID   =  $(this).attr('class').replace('reply','');
$(".reply"+RID).append(data.responseText);
$(".reply"+RID).fadeIn(2000);
    }
});
}

    //on submit reply
$(".repfrm").click(function(){
error.fadeOut();
var author = inputAuthor.attr("value");
var url = inputUrl.attr("value");
var img = inputImg.attr("value");
var replycom = inputReplycom.attr("value");
var parent_id = inputparent_id.attr("value");
var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value");

        $(".loader").fadeIn(400).html('<br><img src="loaders.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Update...</span>');
        //send the post to submit.php
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "reply.php", 
        data: "action=insert&author="+ author + "&replycom="+ replycom + "&url="+ url + "&img="+ img + "&parent_id="+ parent_id + "&tutid="+ tutid,

            complete: function(data){
            error.fadeOut();
            $(".reply"+RID).append(data.responseText);
            updateReplybox();
            //reactivate the send button
}
});
error_message();
    //we prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form
});
```

Comment: You might have a problem with your ID's. For example the id tutid is used 3 times and you select this by var inputTutid = $("#tutid");

Comment: It might also be the reason for your duplicate entries: #replynext is also not unique, but used to insert the replies. Change your selectors - and create unique ids.

Comment: Tutid is my page id sir.

Comment: you use: inputTutid = $("#tutid"); means document.getElementById('tutid'). Same for: replyList = $("#replynext"); you select a single / unique element but in your case you'll have a collection of elements, therefore duplicate content when updating.

Comment: Edited: Deduct reply list and add a class with id comes from reply.php

Comment: Can't see any changes in your example. Id #replynext is still written multiple times in your html code but used as a single selector in your JavaScript. Replies are sorted strange (shouldn't it be by time)? Happy Coding/ Debugging for you.

Comment: removed Id #replynext

Comment: "*Demo page link will be remove after 2 days for privacy*" - then the demo becomes utterly meaningless for illustrating your problem, if the question requires the demonstration please post a live demo on a site such as here, using [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), over on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar.

Comment: David Thomas, Thank u for this advice. I have no idea about Stack Snippets. I will try.